# How to change log pattern in http_access_.log file under the directory wso2api/repository/logs in WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have updated below configuration in catalina server xml file.

```
Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs"
                       prefix="http_access_" suffix=".log"
                       pattern="combined"
```

Whatever change I did(pattern, directory path) is impacting the files `http_access_Date.log` files but not `http_access_.log` file.

Any suggestions please..

API execution logs are logged to `http_access_.log` file. How do I manage this file and the pattern in this file?

Answer (score 0):

`http_acccess_.log` file contains passthrough and NIO transport traffic-related logs, and that is not configured via the above tomcat valve.

For that, you need to update `log4j.properties` file like this.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.access=INFO
```

and the `access-log.properties` like this.

```
access_log_pattern=%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"
```

See this doc for more details.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Monitoring+ESB+Access+Logs#MonitoringESBAccessLogs-ConfiguringaccesslogsforthePassThroughandNIOtransports(Service/APIinvocation)

Comment: Thanks. I do not have control on log4j.properties file. Actually WSO2 is a container POD in OpenShift. I can see this file when I log to the terminal, but cannot edit or add access-log.properties file. Any other way to do these changes?

Comment: No. You’ll have to take it out as a config map.